# ORA-01981: CASCADE CONSTRAINTS must be specified to perform this revoke

Tags: oracle

I'm getting ORA-01981: CASCADE CONSTRAINTS must be specified to perform this revoke when executing:

```
REVOKE REFERENCES ON dbo.ABC FROM XYZ;
```

How do I address the issue?

Comment: What's unclear about "*CASCADE CONSTRAINTS must be specified*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### try this:

```
REVOKE REFERENCES ON dbo.ABC FROM XYZ CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
```

Answer (score 0):

`REFERENCES` is the privilege which allows us to create foreign keys across schemas. If the privilege is revoked any foreign keys we created on the referenced object must be dropped. The [documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/authorization.htm#DBSEG40048)

> "When a REFERENCES privilege for a table is revoked from a user, any foreign key integrity constraints that are defined by the user and require the dropped REFERENCES privilege are automatically dropped. "

Hence the need for `cascade constraints`.

```
revoke references on dbo.abc from xyz cascade constraints;
```